# Method in Java to compare three rational numbers and return the minimum number

Tags: java, methods

I am required to write a method in Java that compares three rational numbers (randomly generated) and returns the minimum and maximum number. Below you will see that I have written one method to compare and return the maximum and another to compare and return the minimum.

With the two methods below, I am able to get a correct min and max most of the time. However, every few runs I get the INCORRECT min and/or max. I have tried to compare various input data and the results to see exactly where the error is occurring and why it seems apparently random, but I can not find any pattern between the incorrect answers.

For clarification, the program first generates three random numerators and three random denominators, and then uses these numbers to form rational numbers (a/b). The finished program then outputs the Maximum, Minimum, Sum and Average (first in rational number format then in floating point format). My Sum and Average methods are giving correct results every time. The problem seems to be in the getMaximum and getMinimum methods. Around 80% of the time the program gives the correct min and max.

Below you will find the two methods I am having trouble with and their call in my main program. There is also a Die class that I used, but have no problems so it is not included. Please let me know what may be causing the random INCORRECT maximum and minimum outputs (specifically in the getMaximum and getMinimum methods) Thank you.

```
//Method to compare rational numbers and return the largest rational
   public Rational getMaximum(Rational r1,Rational r2)
   {
   float d1, d2, d3;
   d1 = (numerator/denominator);
   d2 = (r1.getNumerator() / r1.getDenominator());
   d3 = (r2.getNumerator() / r2.getDenominator());
   if (d1 > d2)
        if (d1 > d3)
        return new Rational(numerator,denominator);
        else
        return new Rational(r2.getNumerator(),r2.getDenominator());
   else 
        if (d2 > d3)
        return new Rational(r1.getNumerator(),r1.getDenominator());
        else
        return new Rational(r2.getNumerator(),r2.getDenominator());
   }

   //Method to compare rational numbers and return the smaller rational
   public Rational getMinimum(Rational r1, Rational r2,Rational r3)
   {  
   float d1, d2, d3;
   d3 = (r3.getNumerator() / r3.getDenominator());
   d1 = (r1.getNumerator() / r1.getDenominator());
   d2 = (r2.getNumerator() / r2.getDenominator());
   if (d1 < d2)
        if (d1 < d3)
        return new Rational(r1.getNumerator(),r1.getDenominator());
        else
        return new Rational(r3.getNumerator(),r3.getDenominator());
   else 
        if (d2 < d3)
        return new Rational(r2.getNumerator(),r2.getDenominator());
        else
        return new Rational(r3.getNumerator(),r3.getDenominator());
   }
```

Below is where they are being used in the main program...

```
 //Compares the float point formats to find the maximum number
  MaxNum = RatOne.getMaximum(RatTwo,RatThree);

  //Prints the maximum number in rational and float format
  System.out.println("Maximum: " + MaxNum + " (" 
                     + MaxNum.getFloat(MaxNum.getNumerator(),MaxNum.getDenominator())
                     + ")");

  //Compares the float point formats to find the minumum number
  MinNum = RatThree.getMinimum(RatOne,RatTwo,RatThree);

  //Prints the minimum number in rational and float format
  System.out.println("Minimum: " + MinNum + " (" 
                     + MinNum.getFloat(MinNum.getNumerator(),MinNum.getDenominator())
                     + ")");
```

I have a feeling the problem may be with the objects that I am using when calling the methods, but I do not know what other objects would be appropriate. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the numerator and denominator floating-point or integer types?

Comment: @chrylis by the definition of rational numbers, they ought to be integer types; but good question nonetheless

Comment: In `getMaximum` you are doing `d1 = (numerator/denominator);` and in `getMinimum` - `d1 = (r1.getNumerator() / r1.getDenominator());`. Is this correct?

Comment: The numerator and denominator are of int type when used. When they are divided, that answer needs to be a floating point type (e.g. 1/3 = .33333333).

Comment: @Tirath getMaximum and getMinimum are slightly different yes. Originally they were both of d1 = (numerator/denominator) and I had changed getMinimum because I thought that may have been the problem, but both ways are producing the same results, just as they were when they were both the same.

Comment: In the getMax function, if d1 > d2 and d1 = d3 you return d2 which is incorrect. Can you give an example of the 3 numbers producing wrong results?

Comment: @benji Here are two examples of incorrect output... when (1/4)(5/1)(2/6) are generated the program outputs Maximum: (5/1) and Minimum: (2/6) when the minimum should be (1/4). Another example occurs when (3/6)(1/5)(3/5) are generated the program outputs Maximum: (3/5) and Minimum: (3/5) when the Minimum should be (1/5).

Comment: How important is it to have this numerically correct? Ordinarily, rounding errors might cause incorrect results for large numbers, and if you want to avoid those, things get tricky.

Comment: Can you rewrite it using a function that takes 2 numbers instead of 3 and use it twice? for example `getMax(r1, getMax(r2, r3))`

Comment: Thank you everyone! gerrytan was correct in his answer. The problem was numerator and denominator were integers and preforming integer division (which does not take into account the decimal remainder). This was fixed by adding d1 = (float)numerator/denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I suspect is your Rational class is implemented like this:

```
public class Rational {
  int numerator;
  int denominator;

  ..
  int getNumerator() { .. }
  int getDenominator() { .. }
}
```

Recall that performing division over two integers (eg: `getNumerator() / getDenominator()`) will get rid of any remainders.

To give you example, following code will produce 3.0 instead of 3.3333...

```
int x = 10;
int y = 3;
float f = x / y;
System.out.println(f);
```

The much better way to implement this is:

```
(float)x / y
```

Comment: Yes the Rational class is implemented as you suspect. So in the method I have  float d1, d2, d3;
       d3 = (r3.getNumerator() / r3.getDenominator());
       d1 = (r1.getNumerator() / r1.getDenominator());
       d2 = (r2.getNumerator() / r2.getDenominator()); and this is causing the remainder to be ignored?

Comment: Ok great! I thought by introducing d1, d2, and d3 as floats their answers would be of float type, but I see now that integer division is returning an integer answer. Thank you!